# Next Js Typescript getting error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AppProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am getting the error "TS2304: Cannot find name 'AppProps' when I attempt to start a simple Next Js Typescript project. I have read through several other occurrences of this error on Stack Overflow, and I do not think I have similar issues.

```html
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
      <Component {...pageProps} />
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

How can I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing type from the import, like "import { AppProps } from 'next/app';"

Comment: Is that the only way to fix error?

Comment: When I check implementations they dont have the keyword type on the import. Did it solve the issue?

Comment: Which version of Typescript and next.js do you use?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript

But in next js docs, 'type' is used well without any error.

Comment: I'm using Typescript v4.3.5 and next.js v11.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to update TypeScript and Next.js to the latest versions, and reinstall dependencies.
`import type` works on the fresh Next.js install, with the recent TypeScript versions.

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
```

Comment: I think I'm using the latest versions(Typescript v4.3.5 / next.js v11.0.1)

Comment: @Dongs, try to do fresh install or remove `node_modules` and install dependencies again. I have the exact same versions. Also, is it just VSCode error or build fails too?

Comment: does not work for me